# Post meta in functions.php and AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I know that my question seems naive, but I can't cope with this.

Why if I do this:

```
function my_f() {

 $sss = 'some data';
 echo ($sss);
 die();
 }
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_f', 'my_f');
 add_action('wp_ajax_my_f', 'my_f');
```

and then:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.test_btn').click(function() {

$.ajax({
url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
type: 'POST',

data: {action: 'my_f'},
})
.done(function(data) {
console.log(data);

})
.fail(function() {
console.log("error");
})


});

});
```

I see in the console "some data"

But when I'm trying to do the same with the post meta or post id, it doesn't work?

```
function my_fun() {
global $post;

$sss = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'some_meta_id', true );
echo ($sss);
die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_fun', 'my_fun');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_fun', 'my_fun');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no global `$post` in that scope. You need to get set up the global `$post` variable before you can use it. The ajax functions don't run on a particular post or page. So you need to get a post ready with something such as [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/), etc.

You can test this by finding a post with a value on the meta_key `some_meta_id`, and baking in the ID into your function; say Post ID `123` - if you were to do `get_post_meta( 123, 'some_meta_id', true )`; it should work.

---

**edit:**

Per your comment, since you're invoking this on a button click, just pass the ID as an attribute on the `.test_btn`:

```
<a href="#" class="test_btn" data-attr-id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">Click Me</a>
```

And then pass that in your ajax data:

```
var post_id = $(this).attr('data-attr-id');

data: {action: 'my_f', post_id: post_id },
```

Now, inside your function you should be able to access the variable `$_POST['post_id']` which will contain the post ID you passed.

Comment: Can you showcase me how to modify my code on the PHP side to get the meta? It's vital for me to get the ID in my PHP code, grab the data this way and then send the response via AJAX. I know how to cope with this task on the JS/JQUERY side. But I extremely need to grab the ID inside my PHP function.

Comment: Just add the post ID as an attribute to the button you click on. I added some additional code

Comment: Hi, Xhynk, thanks for your advice! Without a doubt, such an approach should work. But what if I need to get the content on page load (without the button click), how could I grab the page ID in such a case?

Comment: $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "I WANT THIS TO BE get_post_meta() ",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{}",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

Comment: You're starting to go beyond the scope of your current question. I'd consider asking another question with your exact desired PHP and JS code that you're attempting.

Comment: Hi, Xhynk! Thanks to your hint I managed to realize that I need to grab the data via jQuery and send it to PHP as a variable! Next, I can use it inside the PHP code!